# Importing from outside the directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have my project structure like this:

```
/application
    /DIR1 
        __init__.py
        file_that_import.py        
        file2.py
    /DIR2 
        __init__.py
        file_tobe_import.py
    __init__.py
```

How should I import the file that is inside `DIR2` from outside the directory?

Comment: [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references). Note that if `__init.py` wasn't a simple typo, you need to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add the paths to the import `path` list like so

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/your/path")
```

Then `import` from those directories